# Windows 8 Changing the logon sound. Puzzled

Tags: windows, audio, login

I am attempting to load a file of my choosing to be run as the logon sound in windows 8.1.  I have gone into the registry editor as per I found on google and edited the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels file and set the DWORD to 0 from 1 so that the logon/logoff display in the sounds list.  I have also created a file under 300kb in a .wav format compatible with windows.  I have set that file as the logon sound and even tried creating a separate theme for the file and using that, but to no avail.  Would anyone be able to tell me what I have missed or done incorrectly please?

Much appreciated,

Saiyori.

Comment: Please post a step by step description of what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8/8.1 you cannot just change logon/logoff sounds as you do for other events.
Go to Task Scheduler and create a task to run on logon/logoff and select the action to run an application or a script to play the sound file that you need. If the default sound is also being played along with the sound file that you selected, then disable the inbuilt sound for logon/logoff.

Instead you can use [Windows Sound Changer](https://varunsharma15.wordpress.com/softwares/windows-sound-changer/) to easily change these sounds. Windows Sound Changer is developed by me. Some features of Windows Sound Changer are :

- Windows Sound Changer is a handy free program designed to change the
  sound for various Windows Operating System events.

  - The program features a simple, easy to use interface to quickly
    change the sound for: Logon/Logoff, Critical/Low Battery Alarm, Exit
    Windows, Print Complete, Minimize/Maximize, Mail and many more.
  - In addition to using custom sounds, Windows Sound Changer also
    includes a Robotic Sound Pack to change all or specified events to
    speak like a robot.
  - A useful play function is also included allowing you to hear the
    sound prior to enabling or changing it. If you do not want the sound
    to be replaced for any event, Windows Sound Changer features a
    "disable" option as well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Also, see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511) Also, if you are the author of the program, you must say so.

Comment: In addition to G-Man's points,  your post points to where the OP can find a solution, but does not actually contain a solution.  It would be more appropriate as a comment, for which you need a little more rep.  Answers should contain an actual solution to the question.

Comment: Thanks for adding the disclosure.  However, this still doesn't explain how to actually solve the problem, it just points to a tool.  Please add the specific steps to solve the problem, the procedure or some screen shots of the steps, for example.  If the process is self-explanatory, nobody would know that unless they bother to download and try it.  This is an opportunity to demonstrate how easy it is.